# Azure MobileSeviceClient InvokeApiAsync - Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException

Tags: json, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to call a method on a custom api controller on my azure mobile services client.

If I hit the path in the browser it returns data just fine. When trying to call it from my app I get the following error

"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1."

```
public async Task<string> AuthUser (string email, string pass)
    {
        var id =  await client.InvokeApiAsync<string>(
            "Login/AuthUser", 
            System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get,                
            new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                {"emailAddress", email },
                {"password",pass }
            }
        );


        if (id != null)
        {
            return id.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Here's the controller I'm calling

```
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web.Http;
    using System.Web.Http.Description;
    using MyAppService.DataObjects;
    using MyAppService.Models;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Config;

    namespace MyAppService.Controllers
    {
      [MobileAppController]
      public class LoginController : ApiController
      {
         private MyAppContext db = new MyAppContext ();

         [HttpGet]
         [ActionName("AuthUser")]        
         public IHttpActionResult Login(string emailAddress, string password)
         {
             var login = db.Members.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Email == emailAddress && m.Password == password);
             if (login != null)
             {
                  return Ok(new {Id = login.Id });
             }
             else
             {
                  return Unauthorized();
             }

         }
     }
 }
```

EDIT: The issue was the return type from the controller. Changed it to string and it worked.

Comment: What does the custom API and the model from the body look like?

Comment: Found the problem. Method was expecting a string and my service was returning an IHTTPActionResult. My bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the return type from the controller. Changed it to string and it worked